# C++: Read from files?

Tags: c++, file, load

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading through file using ifstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619604/reading-through-file-using-ifstream)

I'm trying to find a way to read something from a file, put it into a string and then output it onto the screen. If you know how to do this can you give an example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867067/read-from-same-file-until-eof-using-ifstream-after-file-contents-change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ifstream infile("myfile.txt");
std::string line;

// Reads the first line from the file and stores it into 'line'
std::getline(infile, line);

infile.close();
std::cout << line;
```

This code will read the entire first line of the file.
If you want to read the file line by line you could do something like this:

```
while (!infile.eof) {
  std::getline(infile, line);
  std::cout << line << "\n"; // Not sure if std::getline includes the line terminator
}
```

Not sure what you mean by 'need to read *something*', but you could use a stringstream for conversions.

Answer (score 0):

```
ifstream fin ("input.txt");

char line [200];
streamsize size (200);
fin.getline(line, size);
//or you could do:
//  string str; fin >> str;
//for every space sepped string in the file
cout << line << endl;
```

Comment: Using `std::string` is safer.