# Reading a File Modified by A Different Process/Thread in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, file, ifstream

I want to dynamically read a file for the appended content. The file in written by another thread. I'm using ubuntu, and had a look at inotify, but wanted to try and implement a simple way for this since I only need to read the appended content. What I tried is as follows:

```
ifstream logFile("path_to_file", ifstream::in);
if(logFile.fail()) {
    cout << "file not found" << endl;
    exit(0);
}

while (true) {
    string line;
    getline(logFile, line);
    if( logFile.eof() ) {
        //wait for 2 seconds
        logFile.clear();
    }
    if(!line.empty())
        cout << line << endl;
```

However, when the EOF is encountered, the flag doesn't get reset when there is more content appended at the end and even if I call clear() to clear the error condition. What can be the issue in this approach? Do I need to open the file in a shared mode?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read from same file (until EOF) using ifstream after file contents change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867067/read-from-same-file-until-eof-using-ifstream-after-file-contents-change)

Comment: Thanks, I have already used the clear() method to clear the error flag as mentioned in that question but still have the same issue.

Comment: if writing is done in another thread, why don't you synchronize them somehow?

Comment: Because its not me who is writing and I have no control over it. else of course synchronization would have been the answer.